# How do i reflect property over json and set value

Tags: c#, json, reflection, setvalue

I have a empty json, and a datasource with my datas. But this json is a dynamic object, (sample below).

```
        string json = "{ 'Name': '', 'Address': { 'City': '', 'State': '' }, 'Age': 0, 'Itens':[{ 'Name':'', 'Price':0 },{ 'Name':'', 'Price':0 }]}";

        //dynamic obj =  .... json ???

        foreach (PropertyInfo classProperty in obj.GetProperties())
        {
            classProperty.SetValue(obj, GetDataSourceValue(classProperty.Name), null);
        }
```

....
        private static object GetDataSourceValue(string name)
        {
            // do anything
         }

How can I read this json or others, set values and navigate if has items?

Comment: take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object) post

Comment: means you want to fill your json dynamically by reading its property names?

Comment: Yes, but this json can be many kinds objects